# How to find out contention problems in java when most of the classes are concurrent

Tags: java, profiling, contention, reentrantlock

We used yourkit profiler to find out and resolve many contention issues in our application. We used thread monitoring to see which threads are blocked and resolved many of those issues. But yourkit does not show up ReentrantLocks as blocked or waiting. So what can be done to actually see the contention problems.

Yourkit monitor profiling cannot be relied upon now because we have fixed most of the places using concurrent structures. Now we want some tool to help us find out contention issues including those of Reentrant locks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your kit does support [reentrant locks](http://forums.yourkit.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3362)